# How to effectively update the attributes of an object

Tags: python, object

I am creating a "pet game" in order to train my computing skills in python (that is just an excuse: it is because it is fun).

I decided to do a simple RPG game. For that, I defined the class *hero*:

```
class hero:
    #Common class for the main character
    def __init__(self, name, lvl, str, agi, vit, int, luk, prof):
        self.name = name
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.str = str
        self.agi = agi
        self.vit = vit
        self.int = int
        self.luk = luk
        self.prof = prof
        self.exp = 0
        if prof==1:
            self.dmg=3*(self.str)+1*(self.agi)
            self.skillList=['heavySlash01']
            self.strUp=3
            self.agiUp=1
            self.vitUp=2
            self.intUp=1
            self.lukUp=1
        if prof==2:
            self.dmg=1*(self.str)+3*(self.agi)
            self.skillList=['doubleAttack02']
            self.strUp=1
            self.agiUp=3
            self.vitUp=1
            self.intUp=1
            self.lukUp=2
        if prof==3:
            self.dmg=4*(self.int)
            self.skillList=['fireBall03']
            self.strUp=1
            self.agiUp=1.5
            self.vitUp=0.5
            self.intUp=3.5
            self.lukUp=1.5
        self.hp=19*vit
```

However, I noticed that whenever the hero leveled up, I needed to update all of its status separately. For instance, I needed to manually update the `hero.dmg`. Changing the `agi`, `str` and `int` did not automatically change the `dmg` as I would expect.

My question is then: Is there a way to make the `dmg` automatically update itself, based on its formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `dmg` a property instead of setting in the `__init__` function. The `__init__` only runs when the instance is initialized, which is why things aren't updating. However, making it a property runs the method whenever the property is accessed.

```
@property
def dmg(self):
    if prof==1:
        return 3*(self.str)+1*(self.agi)
    if prof==2:
        ...
```

Comment: All those magic numbers... those really want to live in a config file IMHO.

Comment: I agree, but I also try to not rewrite code entirely when just answering a question so the rewritten code doesn't confuse the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use inheritance in your case:

```
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self, name, lvl, _str, agi, vit, _int, luk):
        self.name = name
        self.lvl = lvl
        self._str = _str  # Should not use "str" because of reserved keyword of the same name
        self.agi = agi
        self.vit = vit
        self._int = _int  # Should not use "int" because of reserved keyword of the same name
        self.luk = luk
        self.exp = 0

    @property
    def hp(self):
        return 19 * self.vit


class HeroProf_1(Hero):
    skillList = ['heavySlash01']
    strUp = 3
    agiUp = 1
    vitUp = 2
    intUp = 1
    lukUp = 1

    @property
    def dmg(self):
        return 3 * self._str + 1 * self.agi


class HeroProf_2(Hero):
    skillList = ['doubleAttack02']
    strUp = 1
    agiUp = 3
    vitUp = 1
    intUp = 1
    lukUp = 2

    @property
    def dmg(self):
        return 1 * self._str + 3 * self.agi


class HeroProf_3(Hero):
    skillList = ['fireBall03']
    strUp = 1
    agiUp = 1.5
    vitUp = 0.5
    intUp = 3.5
    lukUp = 1.5

    @property
    def dmg(self):
        return 4 * self._int
```